# Hide the help menu in 4D

Tags: 4d-database

I am developing an application using 4D as front-end and postgresql as back-end. So i don't want the help menu to be displayed at front-end side. I do some research but i don't find any 4D commands to do so.

Also i went through 4D manuals which states that:

```
4D automatically manages the Help and application system menus. 
These menus cannot be modified, except for the About 4D command,
which can be managed using the SET ABOUT command.
```

Is it really not possible or am i missing something?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are correct. You cannot remove the Help menu or set any of its items aside from 'About'.

You can go through the components and plugins you may be using and remove any of the help files within them so that they don't show up on the menu.

That is about as good a solution as we've come up with.